# SONOS API Question: AudioClip can you queue up more than one clip?

Tags: sonos

If I try to load back 2 back clips, it appears that they interupt each other. The documentation seems to suggest that by using audioClipStatus you get an array of audioClips, suggesting they can be queued.
Anyone has any info on this?
Secondly, I like the "Chime" audioclip and would love to be able to concatenate an audioClip preceeded by a Chime to announce an announcement. It would be great if there was an option like that.
One suggestion to the Sonos Dev team, perhaps allow the loadAudioClip to have an array of clips as opposed to a single clip.
Any reaction from the Sonos Dev team?

Comment: This is possible using my [library](https://svrooij.io/node-sonos-ts/sonos-device/notifications-and-tts.html) or over [mqtt](https://svrooij.io/sonos2mqtt/control/notifications.html#play-a-mp3)